# Incompatible argument type: Required type: array in Mageno 2.3.6 during compilation

Tags: magento2.3

> Incompatible argument type: Required type: array. Actual type: \Aheadworks\Giftcard\Model\DateTime\FormatConverter;

```
namespace Aheadworks\Giftcard\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Composite\Fieldset;

use Aheadworks\Giftcard\Model\DateTime\FormatConverter;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context as HttpContext;
use Magento\Email\Model\Template\Config as EmailConfig;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\FactoryInterface as TemplateFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config as MediaConfig;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session as AuthSession;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context as ProductContext;
use Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface as UrlEncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface as JsonEncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product as ProductHelper;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface as ProductTypesConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface as LocaleFormatInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Locale\Timezone as TimezoneSource;

/**
 * Class Giftcard
 *
 * @package Aheadworks\Giftcard\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Composite\Fieldset
 */
class Giftcard extends \Aheadworks\Giftcard\Block\Product\View
{
    /**
     * @var AuthSession
     */
    private $authSession;

    /**
     * @param ProductContext $context
     * @param UrlEncoderInterface $urlEncoder
     * @param JsonEncoderInterface $jsonEncoder
     * @param StringUtils $string
     * @param ProductHelper $productHelper
     * @param ProductTypesConfigInterface $productTypeConfig
     * @param LocaleFormatInterface $localeFormat
     * @param CustomerSession $customerSession
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     * @param AuthSession $authSession
     * @param HttpContext $httpContext
     * @param TemplateFactory $templateFactory
     * @param EmailConfig $emailConfig
     * @param MediaConfig $mediaConfig
     * @param TimezoneSource $timezoneSource
     * @param FormatConverter $dateFormatConverter
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductContext $context,
        UrlEncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
        JsonEncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        StringUtils $string,
        ProductHelper $productHelper,
        ProductTypesConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
        LocaleFormatInterface $localeFormat,
        CustomerSession $customerSession,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        AuthSession $authSession,
        HttpContext $httpContext,
        TemplateFactory $templateFactory,
        EmailConfig $emailConfig,
        MediaConfig $mediaConfig,
        TimezoneSource $timezoneSource,
        FormatConverter $dateFormatConverter,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context,$urlEncoder,$jsonEncoder,$string,$productHelper,$productTypeConfig,$localeFormat,$customerSession,$productRepository,$priceCurrency,$httpContext,$templateFactory,$emailConfig,$mediaConfig,$timezoneSource,$dateFormatConverter,$data);
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried passing authSession in constructor?

Comment: Thank you. Already Passed in constructor

Comment: In this `      parent::__construct($context,$urlEncoder,$jsonEncoder,$string,$productHelper,$productTypeConfig,$localeFormat,$customerSession,$productRepository,$priceCurrency,$httpContext,$templateFactory,$emailConfig,$mediaConfig,$timezoneSource,$dateFormatConverter,$data);
` line?